# How to load XML data file into Hive table?

Tags: hive

While loading XML data file into HIVE table i got following error message:

```
FAILED: SemanticException 7:9 Input format must implement InputFormat. Error   encountered near token 'StoresXml'.
```

The way i am loading the XML file is as follows  :

**Create a table StoresXml

```
   'CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE StoresXml (storexml string)
   STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.XmlInputFormat'
   OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
   LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/stores';'
```

** Location /user/hive/warehouse/stores is in HDFS.

`load data inpath <local path where the xml file is stored> into table StoresXml;`

Now,problem is when i select any column from table StoresXml ,the above mentioned error comes up.

Please help me with it.Where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1) first you need to create single column table like

```
CREATE TABLE xmlsample(xml string);
```

2) after that you need to load data in local/hdfs to hive table like

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '---------' INTO TABLE XMLSAMPLE;
```

3) NEXT BY USING `XPATH`, `XPATH_ARRAY`,`XPATH_STRING` LIKE SAMPLE **XML** QUERIES..

Comment: As a result I will have one entry in the table xmlsample for each line within the input file. This means that if the lines within the xml file are not a well-formed xml fragments, then the entries within xmlsample also will not be well-formed. I guess then the methods XPATH, XPATH_ARRAY, XPATH_STRING will not work?

Answer (score 0):

I have just loaded this transactions.xml file into hive table using xpath
for XML file:
**Bring records of xml file into one line:

```
terminal> cat /home/cloudera/Desktop/Test/Transactions_xml.xml | tr -d '&' | tr '\n' ' ' | tr '\r' ' ' | sed 's|</record>|</record>\n|g' | grep -v '^\s*$' > /home/cloudera/Desktop/trx_xml;

terminal> hadoop fs -put /home/cloudera/Desktop/trx_xml.xml  /user/cloudera/DataTest/Transactions_xml

hive>create table Transactions_xml1(xmldata string);

hive>load data inpath '/user/cloudera/DataTest/Transactions_xml' overwrite into table Transactions_xml1;

hive>create table Transactions_xml(trx_id int,account int,amount int);

hive>insert overwrite table Transactions_xml select xpath_int(xmldata,'record/Tid'),
xpath_int(xmldata,'record/AccounID'),
xpath_int(xmldata,'record/Amount') from Transactions_xml1;
```

I hope this will help you. Let me know the result.

Answer (score -2):

I have developed a tool to generate hive scripts from a csv file. Following are few examples on how files are generated. 
Tool -- https://sourceforge.net/projects/csvtohive/?source=directory

1. Select a CSV file using Browse and set hadoop root directory ex: /user/bigdataproject/
2. Tool Generates Hadoop script with all csv files and following is a sample of 
   generated Hadoop script to insert csv into Hadoop

   ```
   #!/bin/bash -v

   hadoop fs -put ./AllstarFull.csv /user/bigdataproject/AllstarFull.csv
   hive -f ./AllstarFull.hive
   ```

   hadoop fs -put ./Appearances.csv /user/bigdataproject/Appearances.csv
   hive -f ./Appearances.hive

   hadoop fs -put ./AwardsManagers.csv /user/bigdataproject/AwardsManagers.csv
   hive -f ./AwardsManagers.hive
3. Sample of generated Hive scripts

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS lahman;

   USE lahman;

   CREATE TABLE AllstarFull (playerID string,yearID string,gameNum string,gameID string,teamID string,lgID string,GP string,startingPos string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile;

   LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/bigdataproject/AllstarFull.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE AllstarFull;

   SELECT * FROM AllstarFull;
   ```

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: Your tool is for csv files, the OP asked about xml. You should delete this as it is not an answer to this question.